# Why standard forbids sizeof to be applied to functions

Tags: c, sizeof

Standard C (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) section 6.5.3.4 says

> The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has
>   function type or an incomplete type

But why ?
Inspecting an executable with `readelf` reveals that functions sizes perfectly know during compilation.

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 67 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
.......
    37: 0000000000400541    16 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 clean
.......
    46: 00000000004005f0     2 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 __libc_csu_fini
......
    49: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5
    52: 00000000004005f4     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 _fini
    53: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_
ed
    58: 0000000000400560   137 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 __libc_csu_init

    62: 000000000040052c    21 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 main
```

Here size `0` belongs to functions from shared libraries, `puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5` function for example. So i checked `libc` information, here is a piece of `readelf -a /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` output related to `puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5`

```
                          Size  Type 
  ...........   
  399: 0000000000070ec0   392 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   12 puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

Is it simply unnecessary feature, or it breaks `C` philosophy, or there some technological issues that i can't see ?

Comment: what if the function was inlined? How can you calculate its size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is because `sizeof` is only meaningful for objects, which have a representation as `unsigned char [sizeof(type)]`. Now in C, functions do not have representations (there is no conversion from function pointer types to data pointer types) so you can say that there is no meaningful usage of `sizeof`.

Answer (score 2):

> Inspecting an executable with readelf reveals that functions sizes perfectly know during compilation.

But if you compile your code with different compiler on the same system, or even same compiler with different optimization options, this size usually changes.For example, if you are using `gcc`, try to compile your code with `gcc -O0` and `gcc -O2`, then compare the code size of your function.

But optimizations made by compiler do not suppose to change behaviors of code they try to optimize. And let an expression have different value under different optimization level is changing the behaviors of code.

Assembler and/or linker could also do some optimizations or modifications to the assembly code generated by compiler, therefore changes the code sizes of some functions.

In addition, C is not a functional programming language, function is not first-class object, which means you could not store it to a variable, pass it as an argument to another function, and so on, it seems pointless to get the size of a function.

Comment: That is why i checked if function size known during compilation. They are known. If the size known during compilation, sizeof can return size of function in current compilation, with current optimizations level.

Comment: But optimizations made by compiler do not suppose to change behaviors of code they try to optimize. And let a expression have different value under different optimization level is changing the behaviors of code.

Comment: the compiler don't know the last size of a function since it may be optimized more at link time

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc i did not know that optimizations done even at link time. Thanks for that point.

Comment: There are [Link-time optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-time_optimization) or [Whole program optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_program_optimization)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Good point, assembler and/or linker could also do some optimizations or modifications to the assembly code generated by compiler for a function, therefore changes the code size of that function.

Answer (score 1):

The main point of C is that it abstracts over the instructions, so you don't have to deal with the binary representation of your program.  This provides a number of advantages compared to assembler -- mainly increased productivity, portability.

A sizeof feature wouldn't all that be useful, since you can't access the data anyway, or copy it, etc., etc.  A system could mark executable memory as execute only, so a C standard that required you to be able to do those things  couldn't be implemented on such a system.

And compilation would be much harder.  It would essentially require a separate pass, after everything is done, to go back through filling in the sizes of the functions.

That being said, it would be a ridiculously awesome feature, you could check if (sizeof(*function) == 0) to see if it was inlined, etc, etc.  However, considering c99 isn't really implemented everywhere yet, I would say even under the best case scenario, it won't be a readily available any earlier than 2050.

Comment: I think it might be useful for different reverse engineering tasks, also it might be useful for small embedded systems, maybe. But it is only a speculation, in practice I never had to know size of function.